# symmetric algebra of a vector space

Tags: tensor-products

Let $V$ be a finite dimensional vector space. If we fix a basis $\{v_1, \ldots, v_n \}$, then how can we regard the symmetric algebra $S(V)$ as a polynomial algebra in the indeterminates $v_1, \ldots, v_n $? Please help me. I am totaly confused about this.

Comment: What's your definition of $S(V)$?

Comment: $S(V)$ is the quotient of the tensor algebra $T(V)$ by the two sided ideal  generated by the elements of the form $v \otimes v' - v' \otimes v$, $v \in V$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not very hard to show this. If you believe that the tensor algebra is the free associative algebra in the basis elements, then you can believe that the symmetric algebra is the free associative, commutative algebra in the basis elements. The polynomial ring is also the free associative, commutative algebra in the indeterminates. Identifying the basis elements with the indeterminates gives you an isomorphism between them.

Comment: If $\{v_1 , \ldots, v_n\}$ is a fixed basis for $V$ and $t_1, \ldots, t_n$ are the indeterminates then the mapping $v_i \to t_i$ defines linear map from $V \to \mathbb{k}[t_1, \ldots, t_n]$ then by the universal property of $S(V)$, we have an algebra homomorphism from $S(V) \to  \mathbb{k}[t_1, \ldots, t_n]$. The map is clearly surjective. How to prove the injectivity?

Comment: @Anupam Probably easiest to define the inverse.

Comment: How? Can you elaborate little more?

Comment: @Anupam I'm done for tonight, will discuss tomorrow.

Comment: @Anupam By the universal properties you can construct maps both ways. Show that the composition is the identity.